# How to change / add new custom error text mysql

Tags: mysql, localization

I understand how it is possible to set a language in mysql.ini but that not available for my country (Indonesia). How can I localize the error text from mysql to match my language.

Example:
`Duplicate Primary Key` should become `Kunci Utama telah digunakan`

Comment: Thanks for advance!